# how to make PostgreSQL to treat two different chars as same

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm working on a project in which a user can search on a product table.

But the problem is the user can set their keyboard layout in Arabic or Persian (as the user preferred), as you may know, Arabic and Persian have common chars except in a few chars like (ك and ک) or (ي and ی) and so on (these letters have the same meaning but different writting).

Now I want the database to return the same result for both letters ك and ک because these two letters have the same meaning with different writing.

Because these two characters have different ASCII then by default Postgres doesn't treat them as the same.

Some solutions are:

1. Replace the letters before comparation (**Has performance issue**).
2. Make the database unification for these letters (**It needs a job to do unification**).
3. Use a custom function in the database to compare the criteria (**I should aware to use the function anywhere I want to search data**).
4. Use Postgres `TRANSLATE` function on the query (**same as cases 1 and 3**).

Is there any other solution to make Postgres treat ك and ک as the same character?? (maybe with custom collation or dictionary)

Comment: You can create an extra auto-generated column that replaces the characters to a common standard, if there is one. For display purposes you still use the original value as typed, but for search purposes you use the extra column. See `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: @TheImpaler, Thank you for your response, as you know, `GENERATED` columns may be a good solution in case of fewer tables, but there are many tables that have the same situation also in some tables there are multiple columns that I have to add generated columns for each of them. What do you think about this kind of table?

Comment: Another strategy is to use custom non-deterministic collations for your text columns. They can be tailored to consider those characters as "equal" for the point of view of a search. See section "24.2.2.4. Nondeterministic Collations" at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html. It's quite an advanced subject, though.